# jQuery dynamic CSS loading weird behavior

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic, javascript

The app I am working on requires dynamic loading of CSS and JS, right now the solution is as follows:

```
myapp.loadCss = function(css){
       $("head").append("<link>");
       cssDom = $("head").children(":last");
       cssDom.attr({rel:  "stylesheet",
                 type: "text/css",
                 href: css
                });  
}

myapp.loadJs = funciton(js){
...
//$.ajax call is used in synchronized mode to make sure the js is fully loaded 
}

}
```

When some widgets need to be load, the usual call with be

```
myapp.loadCss('/widgets/widget1/css/example.css');
myapp.loadJs('/wiggets/widget1/js/example.js');
```

The weird thing is that once a while (1 out of 10 or 20), the newly created dom elements from example.js will not be able to get its CSS from example.css, it seems however my loadCss method does not load the CSS in a synchronized mode? I have tried to replace my loadCss with the the following code:

```
myapp.loadCss(css){
 $('<link href="' + css + '" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />').appendTo($('head'));

}
```

It seems to be OK then (I refreshed the webpage a hundred times for verification :-( )
But unfortunately this method failed in IE(IE7, not tested in IE6, 8)

Is there any better solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can write

```
 cssDom = $("head").append("<link>");
```

This can help because potentially two calls of your script can be started almost in same time and as result you will add two tags  and only one of them will be changed(twice) so one css will be missing.

About IE7 - from my own experience the most common error - adding comma for the last element in dynamic object

```
var zzz = {a:'a', b:'b',}
```